# Initialization of a microSD card using an SPI interface

Tags: embedded, sd-card

I'm using a [microSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital#Physical_size) card in an embedded design. The card is connected to a microcontroller using the SPI interface. It worked fine for all cards I've used before, but now my new card will not initialize. The card is a Transcend 2 GB microSD card (TS2GUSD).

After sending the initial clock train to switch to SPI mode, I do the following:

1. CMD0 (Argument 0, CRC 0x95) -> Response 0x01 -> OK
2. CMD8 (Argument 0x000001AA, CRC 0x87) -> Response 0x01 0x000001AA -> Means it's SDC V2+ card, the voltage range 2.7 V - 3.6 V is supported -> OK

Then I should send the ACMD41 command, but when sending the CMD55 (argument 0, CRC 0) that must precede CMD41, I get response 0x05 -> Illegal Command.
I've also tried to send CMD1 (for MMC cards), but it gives a similar *illegal command* response. The code works fine with my Sandisk 2 GB microSD card.

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I seem to have found the issue. When I calculate the correct CRC for CMD55 and send that instead of a dummy CRC, the command is accepted (result 0x01). If you look at [the physical layer specification](http://www.sdcard.org/developers/tech/sdcard/pls/Simplified_Physical_Layer_Spec.pdf) in section 7.2.2, it explicitly says that:

> The SPI interface is initialized in the CRC OFF mode in default. (except for commands CMD0 and CMD8).

This doesn't seem to be the case with this series of Transcend cards, thus violating the specification. Also in case of a CRC error the reply should be 0x09 instead of 0x05. I've tried to explicitly turn off CRC checking with CMD59, but that doesn't seem to help.

=> Calculating the correct CRC for (all?) commands makes the card work.

I'm in contact with Transcend support about this. If I learn something useful I'll you know here.

Note that I used other 2 GB Transcend cards before, but they were made in Taiwan, while the new one is made in Korea (and seems to be a Samsung card (MMAGR02GUDCA)).

Comment: nice! good you dig the issue up!... I'm just stunned because that seams to point that the USB card readers don't use combo commands.
 You can/should mark your answer as the correct one.
BTW, sandisk, transcent, etc do not have semiconductor foundries... they do controllers and digital design services for their products (they just don't actually fabricate the chips)

Comment: I had to wait 48 hours to mark my answer as correct for some reason.

I think USB card readers will use the "real" SD Memory Card protocol" interface (has higher speeds). In that mode you have to use CRC and there's likely no issue.

Comment: Did you ever get a response from Transcend? I'm guessing you sent the whole last byte as zeroes, causing the end bit to be wrong. The card would be conforming to the specification, and even the error code would make sense. (I left an answer detailing this a bit more, in case you're still interested in the cause after... 4 years)

Answer (score 2):

I had almost the same issue.  When sending ACMD41, I sent CMD55 followed by CMD41.  The response for CMD55 was 0x01, indicating idle state and running the initialization process (this is normal, I think).  CMD41 would respond with 0x05, indicating illegal command.  It turns out that my particular card does the CRC check by default, even in SPI mode, and misreports CRC errors as illegal commands (i.e., it doesn't follow the SD spec).  When I calculate the proper CRC, it works fine.  Here is the CRC7 calculation code I used, it has worked well for me:

https://github.com/hazelnusse/crc7

Unless you have taken care to disable CRC checking, I think it is probably best to assume it isn't disabled and make sure you calculate the proper CRC for each command frame.  From what I can tell, some cards disable it by default in SPI mode and others enable it, even though the SD specification states it should be disabled by default in SPI mode except for CMD8.

Comment: In case you're an extremely curious type, like me, and still care about this after a year: Do you remember what you sent as the last byte containing the CRC? If you sent it as all zeroes, note that the last bit isn't actually part of the CRC and should always be 1. (I also left an answer with a bit more detail about this)

Comment: I have the exact problem as described in your answer and I'm using a Sandisk SDXC card. CMD8 goes fine but ACMD41 is just responded with 0x05 regardless of the CRC (I've brute forced 256 possibilities)
Code of concern is here:
https://github.com/cnoviello/mastering-stm32/blob/master/nucleo-f446RE/Middlewares/FatFs/src/drivers/sd_diskio_spi.c#L354

Answer (score 2):

You said you used `CRC 0` for the failing command. I assume that you meant that you sent the whole last byte as `0x00`. Note that the CRC7 is only the first 7 bits of the last byte - the last bit called `end bit` should always be `1`. So if you were sending `0x00` as the last byte, with `0` as the last bit, the failure would be understandable, and even the error code would make sense. If you send `1` as the last bit, it should work, ie. use something like `0x01` or `0xFF` as the last byte.

Answer (score 1):

It's normal, it's likely the internal charge-pump used to make erase voltage that takes longer than usual to be ready... you have to insist on the CMD55+ACMD41 combo until initialization finishes.

The CMD58 could also help you to check if you're supplying correct voltage levels (sometimes sockets have contact problems).

Comment: The card loops indefinitely on the CMD55 with result 0x05. I've waited more then long enough and nothing changes. CMD58 has the same result 0x05. In the meantime I've pinpointed the issue, see answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Sending CMD0 with chip select(0) alone does not initialize the card in SPI mode.  This only sets SPI mode.
Card is not initialized until ACMD41 returns accepted.  Then CRC is off by default.

Answer (score 0):

Insert several dummy SPI cycles after CMD55 (0xFF sent+received) and before CMD41.

I had to do this for both my old test cards - 16MB Panasonic and Sandisk 64MB.

Note: I realize I'm quite late to the party, but I'm hoping it may help someone in future.