# SD card initialization using SPI interface

Tags: initialization, response, spi, sd-card

I get invalid response codes from my SD card (CMD8, CMD55, and CMD41).

Init routine:

```
SDCS = 1; // MMC deaktiviert
SPI1CON1bits.SMP = 0;
SPI1CON1bits.CKE = 1;
SPI1CON1bits.MSTEN = 1;
SPI1CON1bits.CKP = 0;
SPI1STATbits.SPIEN = 1;

for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    SPI(0xFF);

// RESET
unsigned char rr=Command(CMD0,0);
SDCS=1; // MMC deactivated
/* OK response == 1 */

r = Command(CMD8,0); // Check voltage
SDCS=1;
/*
  esponse ==  0xC1 ?!?
*/

r = Command(CMD58,0); // READ_OCR

unsigned char ocr1 = SPI(0xFF);
unsigned char ocr2 = SPI(0xFF);
unsigned char ocr3 = SPI(0xFF);
unsigned char ocr4 = SPI(0xFF);
unsigned char ocr5 = SPI(0xFF);

/*
  r = 0xF8; ?!?
  ocr1 = 0x0F;
  ocr2 = 0xFF;
  ocr3 = 0xFF;
  ocr4 = 0xFF;
  ocr5 = 0xFF;
*/

SDCS=1;

// INIT
unsigned char rrr = 0;
i = 10000;
do
{
    rrr = Command(55,0); // Next is APP CMD
    SDCS = 1;
    if(r)
        break;
} while(--i>0);

/*
OK response == 1
*/

// APP CMD 41 with OCR = 0x0F??
```

You can read the response codes in the comments.

Is it possible the response code to `CMD8` is `0xC1`? Bit 7 should be 0, right?

Is it a hardware error?

Comment: Some cards basically don't support SPI mode. What card brand? Is it a real card or a fake?

Answer (score 1):

The solution can be found in Stack Overflow question *[Initializing SD card in SPI issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365897/initializing-sd-card-in-spi-issues)*.

In short: Before each command (except CMD0), send `0xFF` until you get `0xFF` as a response.