# SDHC card SPI initialisation

Tags: sd-card, spi, fat

I'm working on an embedded system that currently only supports SDSC v1 cards. As it's getting harder and harder to find cards less than 2 GB, I'm trying to add support for SDHC cards. The communication with the card is done via the SPI bus.

So here is what I'm doing to initialise the card:

- Send CMD0. Card returns 0x1
- Send CMD8 + 0x1AA. Card returns 0x1 and 0x1AA
- Send ACMD41. Card returns 0x0.

Afterwards, I read the [MBR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) and figured out that there is a FAT16 partition at 0x30 [LBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_block_addressing). However, reading a sector from that address (0x30*512) returns a repetition of 0x01 0x09...

- When sending ACMD41, I'm sending command id 0x69. Is it correct? Or should I send CMD55 and then CMD1?
- A diagram <sup>1</sup> shows that I need to send CMD58 and possibly CMD16 after sending ACMD41. Is it necessary? I was able to read a valid MBR without doing them.

<sub>1. http://elm-chan.org/docs/mmc/mmc_e.html</sub>

Comment: I would like to mention [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365897/initializing-sd-card-in-spi-issues), which is related. I've added some information about voltage selection using ACMD41, which I think is important to know, in order to make your code work with more cards.

Answer (score 2):

"ACMD" commands all require a CMD55 followed by the relevant command.

For example, for command ACMD41:

```
SD_command(55, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0xFF);
n= SD_command(41, SD2<<6 , 0, 0, 0, 0xFF);
```

Don't forget to OR in 0b01000000 to the first argument. The actual command isn't 55, it's `55|0b01000000` (`0b01110111`, decimal `119`). I do it in the SD_command function itself.

Interfacing to SD cards is a HUUUUUGE pain, so don't give up. Good luck!